# Conversion into ROS compatible timestamp

Tags: ros, timestamp, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following a [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Sensors)  on laser scanner. But then, there is time-related stuff that I need to modify so that the time is not considered taken real-time(as shown in tutorial, it uses

- ros::Time scan_time = ros::Time::now();
- scan.header.stamp = scan_time;

to realize it. Instead, I want to take time values from a dataset(logfile).

I've tried to do as the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_row; i++)
{
    scan.header.stamp =  data_set[i][1];
}
```

but, it doesn't work..for the line "scan.header.stamp =  data_set[i][1];", I receive the following error:

```
"no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘scan.sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void>     >::header.std_msgs::Header_<std::allocator<void> >::stamp = (((std::vector<double,     std::allocator<double> >*)((PointCloud*)this)-
 >PointCloud::data_set.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp =     std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::vector<double,     std::allocator<double> > >](((long unsigned int)i)))->std::vector<_Tp, 
 _Alloc>::operator[] [with _Tp = double, _Alloc = std::allocator<double>](1ul) / 1.0e+3)’"
```

I cannot see the culprit..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11708/conversion-into-ros-compatible-timestamp/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out the constructors in the ROS Time API.

You can either pass in a Time in seconds (as double) or the single components directly - both as unix timestamp.

What you need depends on the datatype of your data_set.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-28**:
Thanks a lot, it now works, the problem is because I don't pass the input argument to the the constructor of the object..

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2011-10-27**:
When using the the two argument constructor, the nsec parameter represents the microseconds component of time, ie. it is always smaller than 1e9, so if you want to pass 1.5 seconds, it would be: sec=1, nsec=5e8 (and not nsec=1.5e9).

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-27**:
got error: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘scan.sensor_msgs::LaserScan_std::allocator<void >::header.std_msgs::Header_std::allocator<void >::stamp = (((void)(((std::vector<double, std::allocator >*)((PointCloud*)this)->PointCloud::data_set.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-27**:
It seems OK now, but is it true just to convert like that? I input those 2 "identical" arguments in s and ns? I have only one timestamp anyway in my dataset..

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-27**:
@tfoote: I've tried to use the one takes 2 constructor like this: "scan.header.stamp =  ((data_set[z][1])/1000, (data_set[z][1])*pow(10,6)) ;", but then it says that "value computed is not used" on that line of code.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-27**:
The two argument constructor takes seconds and nano seconds. That's likely the easiest way to use your number.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-10-27**:
The time in my dataset is in milliseconds, that means I need to convert it to seconds, am I right that way? It is in int, I perhaps can just type-cast it to double..